# Comparing and accessing values from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm IT administrator trying to learn some scripting in Python 3.x. so forgive me my lack of knowledge for now. :-)

I have a list of dictionaries (`start_sequence` variable). I want to compare key values between neighbouring dictionaries in list, so I wrote this code:

```
start_sequence = [{'server': 'server1', 'service': 'service1', 'startup': 'Automatic', 'os': 'Windows', 'order': 1}, 
                  {'server': 'server2', 'service': 'service2', 'startup': 'Automatic', 'os': 'Windows', 'order': 1}, 
                  {'server': 'server3', 'service': 'service2', 'startup': 'Automatic', 'os': 'Windows', 'order': 1}, 
                  {'server': 'server4', 'service': 'service3', 'startup': 'Automatic', 'os': 'Windows', 'order': 2}, 
                  {'server': 'server5', 'service': 'service4', 'startup': 'Automatic', 'os': 'Windows', 'order': 3}]

for i in range(0, len(start_sequence) - 1):
    print('i=', i, ':', start_sequence[i]['server'], start_sequence[i]['service'])
    if start_sequence[i]['order'] != start_sequence[i + 1]['order']:
        print('delay')
print('i=', len(start_sequence) - 1, ':', start_sequence[len(start_sequence) - 1]['server'],start_sequence[len(start_sequence) - 1]['service'])
```

At this stage this is just to print servers and services from the list and to put a 'delay' basing on order key differences (some services will need to wait until previous are up and running).

And to be honest I don't like this loop too much. It works but I bet it could be written better. For example I don't like this line after the loop just to fix 'list index out of range' issue. Do you have any hints how this could be optimized?

Comment: can you please add any sample input and output ?

Comment: to be honest if you're going to be comparing every item with the next one you need to check if you're out of bounds. Otherwise, you could do `for item in start_sequence`, skip the rest of the code only the first time, store the current item in a variable and in the next iteration compare that variable to the new item the loop has taken

Comment: In *Pythonland*, juggling with index positions that much can get you arrested.

Comment: @VikasDamodar I'v just added them to the main post, sorry for that.

Comment: @Shinratensei is this what you meant? -> https://pastebin.com/TSdu0KTL

Comment: @Ev.Kounis is code from above link any better? I don't want to get arrested, I'm good citizen!

Comment: Yes, something like that

Comment: @Kokos Very much so; it is nicer to look at.

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be to use the `zip` function in Python.  This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. This could help you iterate the elements:

```
for thiselem,nextelem in zip(li, li[1 : ] + li[ : 1]):
```

*Note that the only difference is that the last iteration this will give you as `thislem` the last element in you list and as 'nextelement' the very first.*

Here is an example on your data:

```
for thiselem,nextelem in zip(start_sequence, start_sequence[1 : ] + start_sequence[ : 1]):
  print('THIS: ' + str(thiselem))
  print('NEXT: ' + str(nextelem) + '\n')
```

Result

> THIS: {'server': 'server1', 'order': 1} NEXT: {'server': 'server2',
>   'order': 1}
>
> THIS: {'server': 'server2', 'order': 1} NEXT: {'server': 'server3',
>   'order': 1}
>
> THIS: {'server': 'server3', 'order': 1} NEXT: {'server': 'server4',
>   'order': 2}
>
> THIS: {'server': 'server4', 'order': 2} NEXT: {'server': 'server5',
>   'order': 3}
>
> THIS: {'server': 'server5', 'order': 3} NEXT: {'server': 'server1',
>   'order': 1}